# python tz_localize: NonExistentTimeError due to DST

Tags: python, date, pandas, timezone, pytz

I have a dataframe 's15_d' (143977 rows) with a tz-naive column 'actual_datetime' (with flight departures from the summer 2015 schedule from 2015-03-29 00:00:00 up until 2015-10-24 00:00:00. It's exactly the period Euope/Amsterdam is on daylight savings time (DST)). I want to localize to a given time zone('Europe/Amsterdam') before converting it into UTC. In the localize-phase, things go wrong: NonExistentTimeError: 2015-03-29 02:15:34

I first cast to datetime64[ns]

```
s15_d.actual_datetime = s15_d.loc[:, ('actual_datetime')].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' , infer_datetime_format = True))
```

output (first 10 rows) looks like this:

```
2015-10-24 23:57:35
2015-10-24 23:50:52
2015-10-24 23:02:11
2015-10-24 22:33:09
2015-10-24 22:22:11
2015-10-24 22:19:17
2015-10-24 22:16:45
2015-10-24 22:13:20
2015-10-24 22:06:30
2015-10-24 21:59:19
```

If I run

```
s15_d.actual_datetime.dt.tz_localize('Europe/Amsterdam')
```

The exception 'NonExistentTimeError' is raised from pytz when attempting to localize a datetime that doesn't exist in the time zone specified.
Ok clear so apparently the '2015-03-29 02:15:34' timestamp causes the problem but this is **not** even in the actual_datetime column:

```
s15_d[s15_d.actual_datetime == '2015-03-29 02:15:34']
```

returns no rows so the raised error is on a non-existing date not even in the dataframe. Any ideas how this can this be solved ? Maybe get rid of all the rows that are just in the hour that Holland switches to DST (from 02:00 till 03:00? )Tried plenty of things already.

last point. If I filter out the datetime rows that are in the DST 'danger-zone' like so:

```
S15_filtered = s15_d[(s15_d.actual_datetime > '2015-03-29 05:00:00')]
```

the tz_localize works but I would like to include those values also, not excluding them. thnx

Comment: are you sure the comparisons use the same timezone? (how `'2015-03-29 02:15:34'` is interpreted? Is it local timezone? Is it UTC?) Is your local timezone is  `'Europe/Amsterdam'`?

Comment: To debug, can you iteratively select a smaller subset of the dataframe that still raises the error? Until you can isolate the line(s) / date(s) that give rise to the error. And if possible, provide a self-contained reproducible example.